# Capturing Group with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am using the code as follows,

**Code:**

```
 my $str = 123455;

if ($str =~ m/([a-z]+)|(\d+)/ {
   print "$1\n";
}
```

I know that it will not print the result because we should give $2. But I want to get the result as it is using the same code by changing the regular expression.

Is it possible to do it?

**Note :**

Please do not provide the result as below,

```
 my $str = 123455;

if ($str =~ m/(?:[a-z]+)|(\d+)/ {
   print "$1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `(?| .. )` for [alternative capture group numbering](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Alternative-capture-group-numbering),

```
use 5.010; # regex feature available since perl 5.10

my $str = 123455;

if ($str =~ m/(?| ([a-z]+)|(\d+) )/x) {
   print "$1\n";
}
```

Comment: It is not working in JavaScript. Is there any option is there for JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

```
([a-z]+|\d+)
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sZ2wJ5/1

Add anchors if you want to match only letters or numbers at a time.

```
^([a-z]+|\d+)$
```

or

```
((?:[a-z]+)|(?:\d+))
```

Comment: my aim is use two capturing groups but I want to get the result is in $1. I don't want to change the group structuring.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `print "$&\n"`.

**$&** contains the *entire matched string* (in other words : either $1 or $2).

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html for more details ;-)

Comment: -1: Usage of the `$&` variable reduces performance on many perl versions. It should be avoided, and that isn't hard: I've never encountered a situation where using `$&` was the only option (usually, it's better to put the whole pattern into a capture).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you don't want to change your group structuring?  You want your capture to go to group 1, but what you have won't ever put a number in group 1.  You *have* to change your group structuring.
If you still want to be able to find a numeric in group 2, you can create subgroups -- groups number from the opening parenthesis.  Try

```
([a-z]+|(\d+))
```

if that's what you want.